# Allow WebSockets in Google Compute Engine (GCE)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I'm using Compute Engine (GCE) to run my socket server with Socket.IO (Node.js)

It's only working with polling. When I try to use a web client I receive this error code:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp-socket.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Tt4uNFR2fU82zsCIAADo' failed: Unexpected response code: 400
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it GCE configuration problem?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @NewtonJoshua, details about infra? You using Nginx?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: No. I'm not using Nginx. There is a Node server and Angular client using socket.io.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -v http://myapp-socket.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Tt4uNFR2fU82zsCIAADo`

Comment: Is this compute engine ? *.appspot.com is the domain for AppEngine.

Comment: @TarunLalwani: it is throwing timeout error

Comment: @koma: It s compute engine

Comment: connection to 'https://my-web-site.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-RFvp2' is throwing timeout error

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use the myapp-socket.appspot.com domain in your script when using WebSockets.  Instead, you will need to use the external ip of the GCE instance and connect directly to that, opening any firewall ports you may be using.

I believe traffic going to the appspot.com domain is also going through frontend webservers and socket.io needs a direct connection to the server.

Comment: Even after using external IP address the issue persists

Comment: Try out all solutions in pre-existing [issue#1942](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) of socket.io

Comment: I am having this issue. Using the IP works but my custom domain does not. Is there any configuration I can update so that I can use my own domain?

Comment: Got it to work using my custom domain. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299921/4020228 . According to the thread linked in that answer, if you need to address your server using it's IP address, you have done something wrong

Answer (score 2):

The Virtual Machines in Google Compute Engine have port 80 for http and port 443 for https. Using these ports for web-sockets solved the issue.