# Websocket connection on Google Compute Engine using a custom domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-compute-engine

I have a websocket server (node.js) which runs fine on localhost and on a previous heroku deployment. I am now migrating to google compute engine and running into some issues.

The websocket handshake is failing returning a 301 error. As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292133/4020228) this can be due to the request going through front end servers that do not support a websocket connection and can be worked around by targeting `ws://my_external_gce_ip` directly. I am wondering if there is some load balancing configuration I can update so that I can address my backend using the custom domain name.

While I understand the problem, it seems to me that the domain should be resolved to the external ip after a dns lookup so I don't understand the constraint really.

Sorry if this is very obvious. I'm new to GCE and have been googling all day trying to get this. I will paste my code below as well as the NGINX config but I don't think either are particularly helpful as all works fine addressing using the IP

index.js:

```
/* requirements */
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/*
server definition and config
*/
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const server = http.createServer(app);

/*
web socket stuff
*/

const webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({
    server,
});

webSocketServer.on("connection", (webSocket) => {
    console.log("board trying to connect...");
    webSocket.on("message", (data) => {
        webSocketServer.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (client === webSocket && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send("[SERVER MESSAGE]: You are connected to the server :)");
            }
        });
    });
});

/*
activate server
*/
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on port ${port}\n`);
});
```

nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;

        location \ {
                # we're actually going to proxy all requests to
                # a Nodejs backend
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                # I added this baby in
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
server 
{
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name my_domain; # managed by Certbot
        location / {
                # we're actually going to proxy all requests to
                # a Nodejs backend
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server 
{
    if ($host = my_domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name my_domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Thanks very much in advance and sorry if this is a noob question. Total noob when it comes to load balancing

Answer (score 3):

Solved. After a lot more googling I found [this thread](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) of people facing the same problem most either using apache servers or elastic beanstalk so not using nginx.

It seems that a lot of people get websockets to "work" using socket.io but they don't really have a duplex connection as it is falling back to long polling.

In my case the answer was simple, I didn't include the server name in my nginx (facepalm) and I may have forgot to include a header. The https forwarding now looks like this (and addressing using my domain works)

```
location / {
                # we're actually going to proxy all requests to
                # a Nodejs backend
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
              
              
        }
```

Don't forget to restart your nginx after you update

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```